# Actualizar objeto en un array de objetos

Tags: javascript, ionic

Estoy haciendo un array object para guardar datos de productos como nombre, precio, cantidad etc,  al cual para guardarlo utilizo un push; sin embargo cuando actualizo una cantidad del producto el push hace que se me duplique el objeto, es decir que si yo tenia un producto con una cantidad de 2 y leiugo la actualizo por una cantidad de 5 en el object array en vez de que me salga un solo array object con el valor de 5, me sale dos uno con la cantidad original y otro con la cantidad actualizada.

Aquí el código:

```
  $scope.getItemToSend ={item:stockitem, cantidadItem: $scope.count, notaItem:$scope.nota , valorReemplazo:$rootScope.valorreemplazoitem, cantidadReemplazo:$rootScope.countreemplazoitem, notaReempplazo: $rootScope.notareemplatoitem, nombreReemplazo:  $rootScope.reemplazoname, itemReemplazo:$rootScope.itemreemplazo, positionOrder: $rootScope.position_order, origen: 'app_mobile'};

 $scope.getItemstoBuy.push($scope.getItemToSend)
```

Como puedo controlar para que se actualize el array object sin que se repita el object del producto

Answer (score 2):

Cuando utilizas el método `Array.prototype.push()` lo que estás haciendo es añadir al array un nuevo elemento.

Lo que debes hacer para modificar un elemento del array es encontrar el elemento que quieres modificar con el método `.find()` y en base a eso, modificarlo.

Te dejo un pequeño snippet para que puedas probarlo.

```js
let myArr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    price: 20,
    amount: 3
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    price: 10,
    amount: 1,
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    price: 5,
    amount: 16,
  },
];

let myObj = myArr.find(el => el.id=1);

myObj.amount = 25;

console.log(myArr);
```